# Activate Bitlocker on external drive with powershell

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

I'm trying to encrypt an external drive via powershell with bitlocker.

The script i'm posting here will be part of a bigger setup where all attached disks to a pc will be automaticly formatted and then have bitlocker enabled on them. 
I'm trying to set a password for unlocking the volume *and* export a recovery key incase worst case scenario passes...

the code:

```
$Pass = 'xxxxx.' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "E:" -EncryptionMethod Aes256  -UsedSpaceOnly -PasswordProtector -Password $Pass 
Add-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint "E:" -RecoveryKeyPath "D:\keys\" -RecoveryKeyProtector

do 
{
$Volume = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint E:
Write-Progress -Activity "Encrypting volume $($Volume.MountPoint)" -Status "Encryption Progress:" -PercentComplete $Volume.EncryptionPercentage
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
until ($Volume.VolumeStatus -eq 'FullyEncrypted')

Write-Progress -Activity "Encrypting volume $($Volume.MountPoint)" -Status "Encryption Progress:" -Completed
```

I'm getting an error : parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

Isn't it possible to both use the password and recoverykey action when bitlocking?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can only add one protector per call. If you want two protectors, then you should use `Add-BitLockerKeyProtector` before of after `Enable-BitLocker`. Also, you do not need to wait for `FullyEncrypted` state before calling `Enable-BitLockerAutoUnlock`.

Comment: as you can see (even before my edit) i allready wait for fully encrypted state

Comment: And I say you do **not** need that wait. You can call `Add-BitLockerKeyProtector` even before you enable BitLocker on volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use both a password and recovery key when calling `Enable-BitLocker`.

From [TechNet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/enable-bitlocker?view=win10-ps): "You can specify only one of these methods or combinations when you enable encryption, but you can use the Add-BitLockerKeyProtector cmdlet to add other protectors."

So use `Add-BitLockerKeyProtector` after enabling.

Comment: updated the first post with an updated script, don't get an export from a key though

Comment: @Michael Just add password protection with `Enable-BitLocker`. Then add recovery key afterwards, using `Add-BitLockerKeyProtector`. You don't need the second call to `Enable-BitLocker`.

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't understand what you mean. I've removed the 2Nd enable-bitlocker, but how do i specify the recovery key path then? If i just put them one line after the other it doesn't work

Comment: ok figured it out, but still don't get any visible output in the D:\keys folder

Comment: *don't get any visible output in the D:\keys folder* @Michael Did you enable showing hidden and system files?

Comment: @PetSerAl I did, the keys are exported in .deb files. Which remain invisible even with hidden files set to visible. 
I changed the setup from keys to password, a 48 digit recovery password should be safe enough for my purposes.